# How to get nohup to exit cleanly when using file redirect

Tags: background-process, nohup

Using the following command:

```
nohup tail -f file | stdbuf -o0 awk '/string1/ && /string2/' > file &
```

This creates data in my file which is what I want but this also gives me the following:

```
[2] 13717
[root@server]# nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
```

From there I have to ctrl-c to get back to a prompt. What do I need to change to get back to a prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually have a prompt.  What is happening is that you are getting it *before* `nohup` reports its warnings about stdin and stdout.  If you type a command, it will run just as you would expect it to notwithstanding the visually unorthodox apparent expansion to your prompt.

If this is truly offensive to your sensibilities, you can [work around it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626195/1421075) with a subshell:

```
$ (nohup stuff and things > logfile & ) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Alternatively, you can address the warnings.  You are being warned because you are not handling standard input and standard error.  If you handle them yourself, `nohup` has nothing to change and so it will be silent:

```
$ nohup stuff and htings > logfile 2> errfile < /dev/null &
```

If you do not want to capture standard error, you can use `/dev/null` for your error file; if you want it to go to the same place as standard output, you can use `2>&1`.

Comment: Is there any way to have it exit cleanly?

Comment: Lol, yes, it is VERY offensive to my sensibilities.